Dynamic Addition of Query Runners in Redash Without Rebuilding
I'm new to Redash and exploring its capabilities. I'm interested in adding new query runners dynamically without rebuilding the entire application. From my understanding, adding a new query runner typically requires modifying the core codebase and redeploying Redash.
Is there a way for a Redash to add new query runners dynamically at runtime, without rebuilding and redeploying the entire application?
I've looked through the Redash documentation and haven't found any clear information on dynamic query runner addition. I'm not sure if this is possible or if there are any workarounds.
